# Get absolute path in Python

Tags: python, python-3.4

I'm having a problem with assigning static files containing resources.

My working directory structure is:

```
|- README.md
|- nlp
|   |-- morpheme
|   |-- |-- morpheme_builder.py
|   |-- fsa_setup.py
| - tests
|   |-- test_fsa.py
| - res
|   |-- suffixes.xml
```

The code for `fsa_setup.py` is:

```
class FSASetup():
    fsa = None
    def get_suffixes():
        list_suffix = list()
        file = os.path.realpath("../res/suffixes.xml")
        .....
if __name__ == "__main__":
    FSASetup.get_suffixes()
```

The code for `morpheme_builder.py` is:

```
class MorphemeBuilder:
    def get_all_words_from_fsa(self):
        ......
if __name__ == "__main__":
    FSASetup.get_suffixes()
```

When it is called in `fsa_setup.py`, the file path's value is '\res\suffixes.xml' and that is correct, but when the other case realized, the file path value is '\nlp\res\suffixes.xml'.

I know how it works like this. So how can I give the path of the resource to the ***file***.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `morpheme_builder.py` is in the directory `morphem`. So when you say `../res/suffixes.xml` it will go on directory back ... so it will go to `nlp/res/suffixes.xml`. What about if you use `os.path.abspath("../res/suffixes.xml")`?